# Why are attributes of a Process object not kept after run?

Tags: python, object, process, attributes, python-multiprocessing

I have the following subclass of `Process`:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyProcess(Process):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.my_attribute = "debug0"
        print("my_attribute : ", self.my_attribute)

        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.my_attribute = "debug1"
        print("my_attribute : ", self.my_attribute)

    def run(self):
        self.my_attribute = "debug2"
        print("my_attribute : ", self.my_attribute)


my_process = MyProcess()

my_process.start()
my_process.join()

print("my_process.my_attribute : ", my_process.my_attribute)
```

I get the following logs:

```
my_attribute :  debug0
my_attribute :  debug1
my_attribute :  debug2
my_process.my_attribute :  debug1
```

Why does the attribute `my_attribute`, while being changed during `run` is not kept as set in the `run` method? How can I set an attribute in this case that keeps its value when the `run` function has finished executing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The run function runs in a separate process, with its own memory space and its own copy of the `my_process` object, so it can't directly affect the `my_process` object in the parent process.  If you want something to change in the parent process when the run function runs in the child process, you will have to arrange some kind of interprocess communication.  This won't happen automatically as a result of using the `Process` class.

Comment: Thanks Dennis, I understand now. I thought the entire `my_process` object would be in a separate process, not just the `run` function. I will try to do `Queue` as an interprocess communication, but I'm already getting a deadlock. Well, multiprocessing is harder than I thought 